# Golang separating items with comma in template

Tags: go

I am trying to display a list of comma separated values, and don't want to display a comma after the last item (or the only item if there is only one).

My code so far:

```
Equipment:
    {{$equipment := .Equipment}}
    {{ range $index, $element := .Equipment}}
        {{$element.Name}}
        {{if lt $index ((len $equipment) -1)}}
            ,
        {{end}}
    {{end}}
```

The current output: `Equipment: Mat , Dumbbell ,`
How do I get rid of the trailing comma

Answer (score 125, accepted):

A nice trick you can use is:

```
Equipment:
    {{$equipment := .Equipment}}
    {{ range $index, $element := .Equipment}}
        {{if $index}},{{end}}
        {{$element.Name}}
    {{end}}
```

This works because the first index is `0`, which returns `false` in the `if` statement. So this code returns `false` for the first index, and then places a comma in front of each following iteration. This results in a comma separated list without a leading or trailing comma.

Comment: Also, you can still refer to fields without `$element`: `{{.Name}}`.

Comment: Why do you need `$equipment` variable?

Comment: Do you know how to remove the space before each comma? This currently outputs: "one , two , three"

Comment: You can remove leading spaces with {{- and trailing spaces with -}}. See the text/template docs on Text and spaces: https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Text_and_spaces

Answer (score 41):

Add a template function to do the work for you. `strings.Join` is perfect for your use case.

Assuming `tmpl` contains your templates, add the `Join` function to your template:

```
tmpl = tmpl.Funcs(template.FuncMap{"StringsJoin": strings.Join})
```

Template:

```
Equipment:
    {{ StringsJoin .Equipment ", " }}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/f_ciPRYIiQ)

Docs: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#FuncMap

Answer (score 2):

#### without index

it can be useful for any iteration, like on maps that do not have index:

```
    {{ $first := true }}
    {{ range $_, $element := .}}
        {{if not $first}}, {{else}} {{$first = false}} {{end}}
        {{$element.Name}}
    {{end}}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/auRRq6Wo1bU)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to skin the cat, if you can create a new type for the field.

```
type MyList []string

func (list MyList) Join() string {
    return strings.Join(list, ", ")
}
```

Then you can use the function in the template like regular:

```
{{ .MyList.Join }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use an external library, it seems like sprig library has a "join" function (see [here](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/string_slice.html)):

> ## join
>
> Join a list of strings into a single string, with the given separator.
>
> ```
> list "hello" "world" | join "_"
> ```
>
> The above will produce hello_world
>
> join will try to convert non-strings to a string value:
>
> ```
> list 1 2 3 | join "+"
> ```
>
> The above will produce 1+2+3