# Get iterator index in go template (consul-template)

Tags: loops, dictionary, go, go-templates, consul-template

I'm trying to get a simple index that I can append to output of a Go template snippet using consul-template.  Looked around a bit and couldn't figure out the simple solution. Basically, given this input

```
backend web_back
    balance roundrobin
    {{range service "web-busybox" "passing"}}
        server  {{ .Name }} {{ .Address }}:80 check
    {{ end }}
```

I would like to see `web-busybox-n 10.1.1.1:80 check`

Where n is the current index in the range loop.  Is this possible with range and maps?

Answer (score 0):

There is no iteration number when ranging over maps (only a value and an optional key). You can achieve what you want with custom functions.

One possible solution that uses an `inc()` function to increment an index variable in each iteration:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "inc": func(i int) int { return i + 1 },
    }).Parse(src))

    m := map[string]string{
        "one":   "first",
        "two":   "second",
        "three": "third",
    }

    fmt.Println(t.Execute(os.Stdout, m))
}

const src = `{{$idx := 0}}
{{range $key, $value := .}}
    index: {{$idx}} key: {{ $key }} value: {{ $value }}
    {{$idx = (inc $idx)}}
{{end}}`
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Payground](https://play.golang.org/p/slVyyyFlOzs)) (compacted output):

```
index: 0 key: one value: first
index: 1 key: three value: third
index: 2 key: two value: second
```

See similar / related questions:

[Go template remove the last comma in range loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662525/go-template-remove-the-last-comma-in-range-loop)

[Join range block in go template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043433/join-range-block-in-go-template)

[Golang code to repeat an html code n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112679/golang-code-to-repeat-an-html-code-n-times)

Comment: Thanks @icza this is pretty hard to understand as a Go newbie.  Any way we can simplify or use something native to the templating language?  I wonder if we could convert the map into an array and then get a range index?

Comment: @4m1r If you are allowed to convert your map to a slice, then there is no issue: ranging over a slice you have the index too.

Answer (score 0):

The example below looks for all servers providing the pmm service, but will only create the command to register with the first pmm server found (when $index == 0)

```
{{- range $index, $service := service "pmm" -}}
    {{- if eq $index 0 -}}
sudo pmm-admin config --server {{ $service.Address }}
    {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```